# #Crystalreports extract a string from a column

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have situation in Crystal reports 11 , where I want to extract string from a particular column which is delimited.

Here is the Example within "":

"06DEC2016 Status
-10, 11, 13
-Parts provided sketches to Bus
-Bus needs to confirm the speed changes and the exact locations
-This change has cost implications and must be recompensed by Bus
-Parts will provide cost proposal
&BIC: Farmer&"

I want to extract everything before the first & delimiter.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split (your_text, "&")[1]

It will split the text for each occurrence of "&", returning an array.

For example, for the text "aaa&bbb&c", it would result in the array ["aaa", "bbb", "c"]. Note that for Crystal, the first index is 1.

Comment: Hi,

The formula validates good, but when I placed the formula in detail section it appears empty and does not show any text.